# VIM: How to filter diagnostics on COC.nvim?

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

I am trying to filter warning messages that warns me for semicolon and parenthesis on a CSS language server to make it work on SASS files.

Answer (score 0):

Set `diagnostic.level` to your `coc-settings.json`.